# How Spark internally works in this scenario?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark

```
  JavaRDD<String> textFile = sc.textFile("C://test.txt");
```

Say I have 1000 line test.txt file. I have single machile with quadcore processor.Here is mine understanding how spark will achieve parallelism here

1. Spark will read chunk of chracters from file in single thread. Not sure is there a default chunk size or it depends on file size
2. Spark will decide how many partition it has to make based on below two params
       a) Data size it has read in step 1 and 
       b) Based on number of cores in cpu
3. Based on partition size in step 2, it will spawn the thread. If there 3 partition , it will spawn three threads.

Is mine understanding correct ?

Comment: as per my knowledge, Spark by default takes partitions as equal to number of blocks of text file. and we can define partitions manually by giving            
 (file path, number of partitions)

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by no of blocks in a file ? Do you mean there out 1000 lines, spark will divide it in some blocks say 4, then create 4 partition and then create 4 threads if on same machine otherwise send it to 4 workers. Is it right ?

Comment: In Hadoop default block size is 64 mb(apache distribution, if cloudera 128mb) If your file size is lets assume 256mb. its by default stored into 4 blocks(4*64 mb). Spark by default takes each block as each partition, and we can manage them.

Comment: Is it valid for HDFS files or file system also ?

Comment: In any file system, but block size may different

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a local file, Spark will split `n` chunks of the file, where `n` is the default parallelism level and equals the number of cores in the cluster (ex. in case of `local[4]`, it will be 4).

We can provide a number of partitions to override that behavior:

```
textFile = sc.textFile("C://test.txt", 8) // will create 8 spark partitions.
```

We can inspect the partitioning:

```
textFile.partitions()
//Array[org.apache.spark.Partition] =     Array(
  org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@cd0, 
  org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@cd1, 
  org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@cd2, 
  org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@cd3, 
  org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@cd4, 
  org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@cd5, 
  org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@cd6, 
  org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopPartition@cd7
)
```

Note that this is a behavior of the underlying hadoop filesystem implementation. For distributed filesystems, such as hdfs, Spark will use the partitioning level of the consumed file. The interaction between Spark  and Hadoop is implemented in 
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/HadoopRDD.scala

Comment: If i  take n hypothetical as 4, it means spark will divide it in to 4 block  each of 250 lines. Right ? Also can you elaborate on `Note that this is a behavior of the underlying hadoop filesystem implementation.  For distributed filesystems, such as hdfs, Spark will use the partitioning level of the consumed file`?  Does system based file or HDFS has its own partitioning level ?

Comment: with `sc.textFile("C://test.txt", 8)` file will be splitted in 8 chunks and if there are 8 cores in a machine , each core can process one chunk. right ?

Comment: @scottmiles that's indeed the expectation in case the operations on the data are parallelizable.